# classpath relative to current working directory when using javac

Tags: java

I haven't been able to find a good answer to this yet, but when using javac, I find that for classpath I can't seem to get it to work using a relative path to the current working directory, although it seems to work for the target directory and source file location. Here is what we're currently using:

```
javac java/src/com/<our-company>/ecommerce/<vendor-tool>/executor/*.java java/src/com/<our-company>/ecommerce/<vendor-tool>/util/*.java -d ./target/java/bin -cp /c/Git/<our-api>/java/lib/some.jar:/c/Git/<our-api>/java/lib/another.jar -verbose
```

And we would like to use something like this:

```
javac java/src/com/<our-company>/ecommerce/<vendor-tool>/executor/*.java java/src/com/<our-company>/ecommerce/<vendor-tool>/util/*.java -d ./target/java/bin -cp java/lib/some.jar:java/lib/another.jar -verbose
```

or perhaps:

```
javac java/src/com/<our-company>/ecommerce/<vendor-tool>/executor/*.java java/src/com/<our-company>/ecommerce/<vendor-tool>/util/*.java -d ./target/java/bin -cp ./java/lib/some.jar:./java/lib/another.jar -verbose
```

The first example seems to work, but the other two get an error that the packages within those jars cannot be found. Since we are using Git, I would prefer the whole build path be relative to allow for wherever the individual's Git repo is located locally--as well as be flexible concerning which operating system they may be using (this is being run in a shell which should operate the same for each of the platforms).

Comment: And do those jars exist in those relative paths?

Comment: You could use something like `-cp ${PWD}/java/lib/some.jar:${PWD}/java/lib/another.jar`

Comment: I know you did not asked for it, but I give some general advice anyway: you really should consider using a build tool. Anyone (including Ant) is better than trying to have portable javac command lines.

Comment: @mustaccio: Excellent--that worked. Thanks.

Comment: @eckes: We are using a Grunt (Node.js) deployment tool as almost all of the project is xml and javascript which is then uploaded to a cloud platform and it tends to work well with what we do. We haven't been using Java on our other projects (and we're trying to be consistent in our tooling) and this will remain very simple compared to most Java builds. If it was a pure-java project with in our company, we would probably be using Ant.